# Asp.net memory issue while file uploading

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory

I have two asp.net pages. In the first page i have a fileupload control and a submit button. In the submit button click event a file will be posted to second page.
The second page receives the file using request.files method. My problem is when i upload a huge file, IIS is using the memory while receiving the file. But it is not cleaning the pool memory after the process. I used GC.collect but no use.
Please tell me how to clear this memory usage.

Gopakumar

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that IIS is using up all the memory?

I would recommend using [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/) to upload larger files. It's way better than the built in ASP.NET stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading whole file at once try uploading the file in chunks.
Or try to profile your application and see which objects are not collected by GC and you can free-up them explicitly.

You can use either [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) or [RedGate profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).